# wp_schedule_event with dynamic names but same function

Tags: wp-cron

I am creating a plugin where I am getting records from the database and dynamically creating events with wp_schedule_event, some sample names:

- ls00_lorem
- ls00_john_doe
- ls00_jane_doe

I am them scheduling these events like so:

```php
public function schedule($interval, $event): void
{
    if (! \wp_next_scheduled($event)) {
      \wp_schedule_event(time(), $interval, $event);
    }
}
```

This would create something like:

```
| ls00_lorem                         | 2023-01-04 17:30:15 | 10 hours 52 minutes   | 1 day      |
| ls00_john_doe                      | 2023-01-04 17:30:15 | 10 hours 52 minutes   | 1 day      |
| ls00_jane_doe                      | 2023-01-04 17:32:48 | 10 hours 55 minutes   | 1 day      |
```

But since I have used the event param as a name I have yet to call a PHP function on them. The third param $event is meant as the name for the function you would like to call. However I want this to also be a unique identifier so I can easily identify (and unschedule) a specific event.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [4th parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/), `$args` is for. Use a single name for the event and pass the unique name as an argument.

```
public function schedule($interval, $event): void
{
    $args = array($event);

    if (! \wp_next_scheduled('my_scheduled_event', $args)) {
      \wp_schedule_event(time(), $interval, 'my_scheduled_event', $args);
    }
}
```

Then you can have a single callback function that has access to the event name as an argument:

```
function my_callback( $event ) {
  // $event is ls00_lorem or ls00_john_doe etc.
}
add_action('my_scheduled_event', 'my_callback', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Hi Jacob,

Thanks for your quick reply! I guess this is what I need but if I understand correctly this would make the `wp cron event list` show up like this right?

my_scheduled_event x 3 times right?

so I still wouldn't know which one it is but atleast I can access the event name and add some logic to each of them.